# Python sending POST requests/ multipart/form-data

Tags: python, api, post, python-requests, multipartform-data

I'm just working on API conection at my work. I already made some GET and PUT request, but now i have problem with POST. [API documantation is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frgBL.png). And here is my code I test but get 400 bad request:

```
import requests

files = {'files': ('fv.pdf', open(r"C:\python\API\fv.pdf", 'rb'))}
data = {"order_documents":[{'file_name':"fv.pdf", 'type_code':'CUSTOMER_INVOICE' }]}

header = {
    'Authorization': '###########################',
}
response = requests.post("https://######.com/api/orders/40100476277994-A/documents", headers=header, files = files, data = data)

print(response.status_code)
print(response.url)
```

Someone have any idea how i can handle with this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the `order_documents` parameter, it needs to be an array and also needs to be called order_documents.

Try changing your `data` variable into:

```
data = {"order_documents": [ {'file_name':"fv.pdf", 'type_code':'CUSTOMER_INVOICE' } ] }
```

The API expects `files` as the parameter name and your dictionary sends `file` to the server. The parameter name `files` that you give to `session.post` is just for `requests` library and not the actual parameter sent to the server.
The API also expects multiple files in an array, so you need to change your files object.

```
files = [
    ('files', ('fv.pdf', open(r"C:\python\API\fv.pdf", 'rb')),
]
```

Also, I don't think you need to use requests.Session(), just use requests.post(), unless you're planning on using the session object multiple times for subsequent requests.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed my code as you suggest, but still getting 400 as response :/

Comment: Are you correctly sending order_id as part of the url? Can you share your new code?

Comment: Have you tried to print the response.text? does that contain any more error messages?

Comment: Yea, I tried. Only this one showed: 
{
  "message" : "Bad Request",
  "status" : 400
}

Comment: maybe you can try using something like Postman to send your request and see if it actually works or what else you might have missed.